# Where and when was the first women's soccer team introduced in the USA?

Tags: football, history

Is there record of the first female soccer team in the US? Which state was the first to adopt women's soccer and when?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first organized female soccer league in the US was founded in 1951 by a priest in North St. Louis, Missouri. This league, known as the Craig Club Girls Soccer League, had four teams that played for two seasons. <sub>([1](http://homepages.sover.net/~spectrum/womensoverview.html)) ([2](http://www.livestrong.com/article/351270-the-history-of-womens-high-school-soccer/))</sub>

The first female soccer college varsity team in the US was founded in the mid-1960s at Castleton State College in Castleton, VT. <sub>([1](http://homepages.sover.net/~spectrum/womensoverview.html))</sub>